# Unable to get data in jquery success call in MVC4 project

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am doing MVC4 project and I am making ajax call to get two properties namely docType and fileName. My server side code is fine. 
This is my server side code.

```
  public ActionResult Download(int? ClientId)
        {
            DcoumentNames obj = new DcoumentNames();
            string docType= objdb.getdocumentType(ClientId);
            string FileName = objdb.GetFileName(ClientId);
            obj.docType = docType;
            obj.fileName = FileName;
            return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

My obj will get values exactly what i required.
This is my Jquery ajax call.

```
 function Download(pClientid) {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            data: { ClientId: pClientid },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("Download", "TestRendering")',
            headers: {
                'VerificationToken': forgeryId
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var temp = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                alert(temp);
                alert(temp[0].docType);
                alert(temp[0].fileName);
                ShowFiepopup(data);
              $("#texens").val(data);

            }
        });
    }
```

I am not able to get expected result in jquery success call. Error shows Unexpected token 0 in JSON position at... Can someone tell me where i am going in or following wrong way? thank you

Comment: don't parse json and see the result...

Comment: Your already returning `json` - remove `var temp = jQuery.parseJSON(data)`. And you not returning a collection, so its just `alert(data.docType);` (but do not use `alert()` for debugging your code

Comment: If i dont parse i will get [object object]...

Comment: i think you are getting already parsed json in succes callback

Comment: dont directly alert the data try and debug the same

Comment: Thank you all. thank you stephen Muecke. Works like charm